# Excel VBA Macro to Look at cell in one workbook and filter for that value in a table in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and I was wondering if there is any way to look up the value in a cell in a separate workbook's table and repeat for the whole column until blank. For example, I have a list of part numbers that I'm trying to look up on another workbook that is very time consuming and I was thinking there may be a macro that I could write to do so.

Basically, the macro would need to take the value in cell A2 (all the way down until blank) and look that specific value up in a filter in a table on an external workbook.

Please let me know if this is within VBA capability, I apprecaite it!

I tried to record a macro that would do it, but it would only look up that specific part number and not *for example* the cell because I would need this to work with many different iterations of the data I receive from the customer.

Comment: This is what a `VLOOKUP` is for.

Comment: Always helps to include the code you have so far, even if it doesn't work.